# How to use checkbox array in VB6

Tags: vb6

Hi guys I need help on how to use checkbox array. I have 4 checkboxes:

- check1(0)
- check1(1)
- check1(2)
- check1(3)

If I check one checkbox the other 3 will disable.  And when I uncheck the checkbox the four will enable.

```
Private Sub Check1_Click(Index As Integer)
   Dim i As Long, ChkCount As Long
   ChkCount = 0

   For i = 0 To 3
      If Check1(i).Value = 1 Then ChkCount = ChkCount + 1
   Next i

   For i = 1 To 3
      If ChkCount < 1 Then
         Check1(i).Enabled = True
      Else
         If Check1(i).Value = 0 Then Check1(i).Enabled = False
      End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

Here's my code but the check1(0) doesn't disable.

---

I fixed it guys thanks for response.
got an error in line 6 it should be for i = 0 to 3

Comment: why don't you use Radio button for this feature?

Comment: I needed to use checkbox

Comment: Is it ok, if you can use JS? because it is not good way to do this in code behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an working demo, I just tested in my VB6.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Check1_Click(Index As Integer)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim isDisable As Boolean
    isDisable = Not (Check1(Index).Value = 1)
    For i = 0 To Check1.Count - 1
        If i <> Index Then
            Check1(i).Enabled = isDisable
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @KentMaquirang I bet my version is the shortest.

Comment: yes, i got another problem  a = iff(Check1(0).Value = vbChecked, "OK", Null) it doesn't work

Comment: @KentMaquirang you may open another question in stackoverflow with full code. Or else I am not sure how you changed my code.

Comment: i can't ask question here right now need to wait 2 days i think

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub check1_Click(Index As Integer)

Select Case Index

Case 0
'Checks or unchecks the first checkbox and gives the other checkboxes the opposite values
check(0).Checked = Not check(0).Checked
check(1).Checked = Not check(0).Checked
check(2).Checked = Not check(0).Checked
check(3).Checked = Not check(0).Checked

Case 1
'Checks or unchecks the second checkbox and gives the other checkboxes the opposite values
check(1).Checked = Not check(1).Checked
check(0).Checked = Not check(1).Checked
check(2).Checked = Not check(1).Checked
check(3).Checked = Not check(1).Checked

Case 2
'Checks or unchecks the third checkbox and gives the other checkboxes the opposite values
check(2).Checked = Not check(2).Checked
check(0).Checked = Not check(2).Checked
check(1).Checked = Not check(2).Checked
check(3).Checked = Not check(2).Checked

Case 3
'Checks or unchecks the fourth checkbox and gives the other checkboxes the opposite values
check(3).Checked = Not check(3).Checked
check(0).Checked = Not check(3).Checked
check(1).Checked = Not check(3).Checked
check(2).Checked = Not check(3).Checked

End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post screenshot or explain why its not working Kent? What is the error message?

Comment: @Ezani Hi, its better if we reduce some duplicate code.